# any simple jquery <table> paginators

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jquery plugin so I can paginate my html tables (the content of which is generated by a jsp c:forEach). But so far I haven't found anything that worked.

The plugin doesn't need to be fancy, in fact something like the first example on http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/pajinate-0.2/examples/example1.html would do fine.

I'm still very new to jquery so I don't have the knowledge yet to write one myself.

So does anyone have any pointers where I could find one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [datatable](http://datatables.net/), it is easy and powerful